# how do you tell if a website is using docusaurus?

Tags: docusaurus

How can you tell if a documentation website is using [Docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/)?

Take for example this website:
https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/introduction

I suspect that it was build with [Docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/) but I didn't find any browser extension to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not built with Docusaurus.

It is simple to identify. Take the Algolia website for example, if you view the page source of any page, and search for docusaurus, you can find some results:

[image]